# Is casting programming to an implementation?

Tags: java, casting

I have a subclass that has an extra method from the superclass so when I need to use that method I need to cast the superclass.

I was wondering if this was a violation of programming to an interface?

If it is, what would be the tradeoff of implementing a blank method of the subclass in the superclass and overriding it just in the subclass that I need it? And if this would make it programming to an interface?

Comment: It is a strong *code smell*, but there are sometimes valid cases for doing this. In general you may want to check the design of your classes and interfaces if you get to this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method is meaningless in the superclass, adding it there simply to avoid casting is not a good idea. If a method is meaningful in the superclass, and it should reasonably take no action there, then you should put the method in the superclass and override it in the subclass. If the functionality of the added method does not belong in a superclass at all, add and implement a second interface in your subclass, and program to that interface instead when you need the additional functionality.

Edit: You can add an interface `WithText`, and add it to the subclass that needs `setText`. If you add more subclasses that need `setText`, make them implement that interface too.

```
interface Shape {
    void setPosition(int x, int y);
    void draw();
}
interface ShapeWithText : Shape {
    void setText(string text);
}
class Line implements Shape {
    // ...
}
class Circle implements Shape {
    // ...
}
class TextBox implements ShapeWithText {
    // ...
}
class CircularText implements ShapeWithText {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I dont need the method for all the subclasses but it also does make sense to have it in the superclass. As I described in my comment for the below answer, an Input doesnt always have a text but there is also a subclass that does need a text, so it isn't totally inappropriate in the superclass

Comment: And for common attributes I can have another class and compose that with the shapes or just have a hashmap that keeps properties, right?

Comment: @eytanfb Absolutely: it does not matter which way you implement common attributes (hash map, class members, etc.) as long as the properties apply equally to all inheriting classes.

Answer (score 2):

`..if this was a violation of programming to an interface?` : Yes, absolutely.

Please refer to [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for details. It is as follows:

> Let q(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then q(y) should be provable for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

Plain explanation can be something like:

It should be possible to perform by referring an `interface` which can be done by a `specific implementation`. If it is not possible then it is violating the contract of using an interface.

For example if something is done as

```
List<String> violating = new LinkedList<String>();
((LinkedList<String>)violating).addFirst("violating");
```

Actually there is no point declaring `List<String> violating` as it needs to use `addFirst`. So it is preferable to use `LinkedList<String> violating` here. This should answer rest of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is **at least** a code smell.

Say you have `class A` and `class B extends A`, and you have the method `foo()` in class `B`. Now assume you have an object of type `A`, which **can be** a `B`. That means, logically, that in your context you need an object of type `A`, regardless of the super type. So why would you need to call `foo()`? If you needed the call, why not have a `B` object in your context directly?

I suggest you only put the `foo()` method in `A` if and only if it makes sense for it to be in A, and not so you can just override it in `B`.

My guess is your design is flawed, but it may just as well not be. In that case, you can use the `instanceof` operator to find out if your object is of type `B`, after which you are safe to cast.

Comment: Amen to probable design issue, 1+ vote. Sometimes it's better for the original poster to tell us what behavior he is trying to achieve, not how he is trying to achieve it.

Comment: I have an Input superclass for a drawing-like application and it needs to support lines and texts. So setting text is just needed in the subclass TextInput. I am already checking with instanceof and safely casting but I just thought I might need to add extra instanceof whenever I add a new input type needing a new function